# ASP.NET MVC automatically adding a slash to empty tags

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.net mvc site with a master page and it has following tag in the head.

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

But when I goto view source in any browser, the meta tag is shown as

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Who is adding the / to the end as />

Issue is when the site is validated with w3 validator it shows an error saying that the meta tag should be closed as > not as />. But I cannot find how the /> is created.

Doct type is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Site is online at http://tipila.com if you want to see it for yourself.

I'm totally clueless here. Any help is appriciated.

This happens in both casini and IIS 7

Comment: curious, if you add a </meta> after the meta tag, what happens?

Comment: You shouldn't really be using runat="server" in mvc unless you have to.  What is your reason for doing this?

Comment: I overlooked it :(, It must've been added by the designer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the `runat="server"` attribute from the `head` tag.

Answer (score 3):

As ZippyV mentions, the problem is the asp.net runtime is rewriting your tags because they're enclosed in server control (runat="server").  I would suggest not using it.

Also, you should really choose to specify the X-UA-Compatible as a header, rather than as a meta tag.  This allows the browser to select the correct mode BEFORE it starts rendering the page.

As an example:

```
void Application_BeginRequest()   
{ 
    Response.AppendHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge");
}
```